# How to write WebSocket output to a text file?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I would like to write the output of a JavaScript WebSocket continuously to a local text file. How can I do this?

Writing to files seem impossible for JavaScript (security reasons). That's why I am searching for another solution. This doesn't need to be a browser based solution. Windows cmd is good, too!

Comment: Have you taken a look at local storage: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

You can store quite a bit of info here and pass it to node backend later as mentioned below to actually generate a file for download later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you seem to already know, you can't write to a local text file from regular browser Javascript.  Security provisions prevent that.  Here are some things you could do:

1. Write a browser plugin and from that you could write to the local disk.
2. Write a local node.js Javascript app that connects to your webSocket and then writes incoming data to a text file.  Then, run that app.
3. Write a local app in any of your other favorite languages (Java, Python, C++, C#, etc...) that connects to your webSocket and then writes incoming data to a text file.  Then, run that app.

FYI, a node.js app to do this would probably be about 20 lines of code to write.